# Any tips/tutorials for creating a multi-level drop-down on-click javascript menu?

Tags: javascript, menu, onclick, expand

I'm currently attempting to learn Javascript so that I can create a multi-level menu that only expands on click. The reason I'm trying to do it this why rather than simply use `element:hover` in CSS is because I have very many menu items in my menu, and when the sub-menus randomly expand on hover "without permission", it can make it harder, and frustrating, to get at certain menu options. Since I want to avoid frustrating my visitors, I'm trying to get it to work "on click".

I feel like I have the basic idea down, but clearly lacking in execution. I've seen samples of other onClick code, but they were only for 1 level submenus, and I have a 4 level menu.

Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/bbm4hzs8/

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar">

<ul id="Nav-Menu">
    <li class="Nav-Tabs"><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul id="Sub-Menu">
            <li class="Sub-Tabs"><a href="#">Sub Menu Links Here</a>
                <ul id="Drop-Menu">
                    <li class="Drop-Tabs"><a href="#">Drop Meny Links Here</a>
                        <ul id="Slide-Menu">
                            <li class="Slide-Tabs"><a href="#">Slide Out Menu Links Here</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="Slide-Tabs"><a href="#">Slide Out Menu Links Here</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="Slide-Tabs"><a href="#">Slide Out Menu Links Here</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function MenuClick( ) {

        /* ------- Defining Variables ------ */

        var Nav-Tabs = document.getElementByClassName("Nav-Tabs");
        var Sub-Tabs = document.getElementByClassName("Sub-Tabs");
        var Drop-Tabs = document.getElementByClassName("Drop-Tabs");

        if (Nav-Tabs.onClick) {
            Parent = Nav-Tabs;
            Child = document.getElementById("Sub-Menu");
        }
        if (Sub-Tabs.onClick) {
            Parent = Sub-Menu;
            Child = document.getElementById("Drop-Menu");
        }
        if (Drop-Tabs.onClick) {
            Parent = Drop.Menu;
            Child = document.getElementById("Slide-Menu");
        }

        /* -------- Parameters ------------ */

        if ( Parent.onClick) {
            if (Child.style.display = "none") {
                Child.style.display = "block";
            }
            else Sub-Menu.style.display = "none"
        }
    }

    /* ------ Activate Menu Buttons ------ */

    document.getElementByClassName("Nav-Tabs").onClick = MenuClick;
    document.getElementByClassName("Sub-Tabs").onClick = MenuClick;
    document.getElementByClassName("Drop-Tabs").onClick = MenuClick;
```

My goal is to have a menu that expands on click, contracts on click, and if you were to click on a different menu item while a sub-menu was open, that sub-menu would close. Does that make sense? I know this code only tackles the expand/contract onclick, but I figure one thing at a time.

I suspect where I'm going wrong is at `if (Nav-Tabs.onClick)`, because I feel pretty sure that's not how I'm actually supposed to target that action, but I can't find reference anywhere, which is probably a sure-fire sign I'm doing this wrong . . . . Help?

Here is a JSfiddle showing how my menu acts on pure CSS. Clearly there are some placement issues that need to be hammered out, but you can see the issues I'm having when you shrink the screen down and try to use the menu. It becomes pretty impossible. 
http://jsfiddle.net/tqbg1rpL/

By the way, if any one has suggestions on how I can deal with this issue in another way, I'm open to suggestions. However, I would really prefer options that are widely supported and would work on smartphones or tablets. There's this one CSS hack (forget what it's called) which apparently works, but doesn't have much support yet.

I look forward to seeing what you guys come up with!

Comment: hi shirley - see my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented something similar on the http://bootcamp.mit.edu/ nav-bar.

I recommend you use a responsive framework such as bootstrap or foundation. It will make your life simpler and you can read the non-minified source files as a tutorial for how these things are implemented in general - there are a lot of fixes for specific browsers and device nuances etc involved. Below is my experience with bootstrap:

First of I used a bootstrap navigation bar http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar and then to get the menu to expand and collapse in the way you are discussing (`on` click and `off` click) I used Yamm: http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/

Comment: Anderson - Hi, I saw this, but I wasn't really sure what to make of it. I'm still not entirely sure what to make of it. It's probably really simple, but my brain wouldn't absorb it so I moved on to trying to solve my problem with jQuery. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question though =)

Comment: Hi Shirley, perhaps I wrote it in the wrong way. Check out getbootstrap.com or foundation.zurb.com  - these do what you are asking out of the box :) sorry it wasn't that accessible.

Comment: Well, I did go there, but that's where I got lost. All I saw was code, with no understanding of how I was supposed to use it or how it worked. I didn't SEE a source code linking it to some external code script. I don't know. I like to KNOW how things work, so if they go wrong in the future, I can fix them.

Comment: Sure, so its based on using external scripts. you can view the bootstrap source here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css  and tutorial videos here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXVoqJEwqoQ&list=PLMvLDJ7usmZB-Mu4kNB-Qtr_1serQjfti

Comment: Anderson - Actually I just noticed a "Bootstrap" tutorial on w3Schools, which is where I'm picking up most of my stuff. I never noticed the link before, but it explains it much better. That might be something I wanna look into in the future, but not just right now.